# Throwable.getCause() executing recursively?

Tags: java, exception, throwable

I am programming backend user validation using Java EE and I have a question about this fragment of code. In the `while` loop, if you look at the debugger and click on cause, it keeps going recursively, even though the Application runs fine (it responds). This is correct code as I have taken it from a handout but it doesn't explain this. I haven't included the whole class, there are many dependencies. Can you please explain me why this is so? Please look at the screenshot from the debugger.

```
@Provider
public class RollbackExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<RollbackException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(RollbackException rbe){

        Throwable cause = rbe.getCause();

        while (cause != null && !(cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException)){
            cause = cause.getCause();       //Breakpoint here
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're assuming that `getCause()` just returns `cause`. It doesn't. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @assylias Tried, no changes

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you please explain? Documentation says "Returns the `cause` of this `throwable` or `null` if the cause is nonexistent or unknown."

Comment: @DreamIT What do you mean "no change"? Does your code run into an infinite loop? Also what I suggested is unnecessary as pointed out by JonSkeet. Your code should work fine.

Comment: @DreamIT: Yes, but that doesn't mean it returns the value of the field directly. Did you read the accepted answer in the duplicate question? Have you tried calling `getCause()` in the debugger instead of just inspecting the field?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok so when you click on debugger `cause`, the cause also includes the recursive reference, but execution of `getCause()` removes this and that is why my code works fine?

Comment: @DreamIT: Yes, exactly. You're examining the *field* `cause`, which is an implementation detail, and `getCause()` checks whether `cause == this` and returns `null` if so.